# Mean.js Stack - export.read with findOne and find functions, call in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jsonp, meanjs

I am new to MEAN.js, and I am a little confused on how to use export.read and call a findOne function with a find function added in.  I have a `customers` module and a `customer-users` module in my app.  I have the customers.server.controller, customer-users.server.controller, and the client controllers.  The customer is like an organization.  And then there are users that fall under a customer.  I can display a customer-users list by itself with export.list in the `customer-users` module. I can display a list of customers in the `customers` module, and then of course I have the customer view when you select a customer.  What I want to do is when you select a customer, the list of customer-users will display underneath the customer name on the customer view.  I have tried to edit the customers.server and customers.client controllers to get this done, but I am unsure of the right way to go about this.

Here is my `customers.server.controller.js`:

```
'use strict';
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
errorHandler = require('./errors.server.controller'),
Customer = mongoose.model('Customer'),
passport = require('passport'),
User = mongoose.model('User'),
CustomerUser = mongoose.model('CustomerUser'),
_ = require('lodash');

/**
* Show the current Customer
*/
exports.read = function(req, res) {
    Customer.findOne({ _id: req.params.customerId }).exec(function(err, customer) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            CustomerUser.find({ customer: req.customer }).sort('-created').exec(function(err, customerUsers) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('error');
                    return res.status(400).send({
                        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                    });
                } else {
                    var customerUsersList = customerUsers;
                    var selectedCustomer = customer;
                    var customerWithUsers = {
                        customer: selectedCustomer,
                        customerUsers: customerUsersList
                    };
                    console.log('1 : ' + customerUsersList);
                    console.log('2 : ' + selectedCustomer);
                    console.log('3 : ' + customerWithUsers);
                    res.jsonp(customerWithUsers);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

I have been trying to debug all the code with all the console.log calls, and everything seems to be giving me the proper arrays that I am looking for.  So I feel that this should work on the server side.

My `customers.client.controller.js` (so far; this is where I am confused as to how to correctly do this):

```
use strict';

// Customers controller
angular.module('customers').controller('CustomersController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Customers', 'AdminCustomerUsers', 'CustomerUsers',
function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Customers, AdminCustomerUsers, CustomerUsers) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    $scope.customerId = $stateParams.customerId;

    $scope.findOne = function() {
        $scope.customer = Customers.get({
            customerId: $stateParams.customerId
        });

        $scope.customerUsers = Customers.query({
            customer: $scope.customer
        });
        console.log($scope.customer);
        console.log($scope.customer.customerUsers);
        console.log($scope.customerUsers);
    };
```

I have tried many different things, so this is not the extent of what I had, but this is the base for my findOne call for the individual customer.

My `view-customers.client.view.html` (which of course will have to be revised upon a working solution):

```
 <section data-ng-controller="CustomersController" data-ng-init="findOne()">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1 data-ng-bind="customer.name"></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="pull-right" data-ng-show="((authentication.user) && (authentication.user._id == customer.user._id))">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/#!/customers/{{customer._id}}/edit">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/#!/customer-users/{{customer._id}}/create">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        </a>
        <!-- <a class="btn btn-default btn-danger" data-ng-click="remove();">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        </a> -->
    </div>
    <small>
        <em class="text-muted">
            Added on
            <span data-ng-bind="customer.created | date:'mediumDate'"></span>
            by
            <span data-ng-bind="customer.user.displayName"></span>
        </em>
    </small>

    <br /><br /><br />
    <div class="list-group">
        <div data-ng-repeat="customerUser in customerUsers" class="list-group-item">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
                {{customerUser.user.displayName}}
                hello
                <small class="label label-default" ng-show="customerUser.admin">admin</small>
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

So my question is how do I get the customer-users list under the customer view?  Am I going about this all wrong?  Is there a better way?  Like I said, everything seems to work on the server side, but I can't call the customerUsers array populated with the correct object on the client side. Is there a way to also use the CustomerUsersController in the view alongside the CustomersController so I can just use the customer-users controller to make this happen?  Because I tried doing that too and failed miserably.  I probably am just missing the logic here. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there code that calls the server (node.js / customers.server.controller.js) from the client?

Since that call will be asynchronous, the Customers.get() and Customers.query() functions should be returning promises. Angular does not automatically unwrap those.

Something like this should work:

```
Customers
    .get({
        customerId: $stateParams.customerId
    })
    .then(function(customer){
        $scope.customer = customer;
    });
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by your question.  Yes, they do return promises.  However the code you posted didn't work.  It said `Customers.get(...).then is not a function` I added `$promise` before the .then function, but not it says $scope.customer is undefined.

Comment: If they returned promises, .then() would be a function (as per the promise spec).

As for the first question... there appears to be a gap in the code you've posted. Your first block of code is running in node.js, which is a **server**. Your second code is angular.js, which runs on the client. In order for the client to call the server, I would expect to see some ajax calls.

Where is **that** code?  The code that contains the ajax calls?  Is there an angular service that accomplishes that?